# How to change boolean variable of an app from another?

Tags: android

I want to build two android apps so that the first one responds to changes of the second.

An example would be an app which has a on/off button that decides a boolean variable of the other application. I know this can be done in the settings of one of them, but I need to make it in two.

I thought maybe making a process that starts when the button is pressed, and a listener on the other app that tells whether that process exists to be able to control the boolean.

But I see this as a resource waster, am I right? what other ways are there to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send by sendBroadcast(Intent) and receive with [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). This should do the trick.